# How can I build and deploy multiple AWS Lambda functions stored in different repositories using AWS CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have multiple AWS Lambda functions stored in separate repositories, and I would like to automate their build and deployment process using AWS CodePipeline. I am aware that AWS CodeBuild can handle the build phase, and CodeDeploy can handle the deployment phase. However, I would like to understand how I can create an alias and deploy a new version of a Lambda function automatically within a continuous delivery (CD) workflow using either the AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK) or Terraform. Is it possible to achieve this, or is it merely a utopian scenario? I have some experience with AWS CodePipeline and CodeBuild but no prior experience with CodeDeploy. I would appreciate guidance on how to approach this scenario effectively

I have been conducting experiments with the AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK) to integrate a CodeDeploy action into my CodePipeline. However, it appears that I would need to create a custom action to achieve this integration. I am hesitant to pursue this approach as I believe it could lead to future difficulties in maintaining the solution. Are there alternative methods or best practices to seamlessly incorporate CodeDeploy within my CodePipeline without resorting to custom actions? I want to ensure a robust and maintainable deployment process for my Lambda functions